# php get url from dropbox

Tags: php, json, dropbox

I am using the php script dropbox recommended https://github.com/BenTheDesigner, and can get a json response, and also list files.

ie This is an output of files in my developer account from test.php.

```
This is a list of all files in your [APP] Dropbox.

 api_upload_test.txt45 bytes
 dsdsdsdsdsdsd0 bytes
  ghhhhhhhhhhhh0 bytes
If I Fell - The Beatles.mp31 MB
 Koala.jpg762.5 KB
 test_download_api_upload_test.txt45 bytes
```

But I need the absolute url for these files. ie 
    http://***something***/sandbox/folder/Koala.jpg

or 
    http://***something***/fileget/http://***something***/koala.jpg

I cannot find anything about specifying a url, or whether I use a dropbox url. Probably a stupid and simple answer.

```
This is an example of the array;
    array(3) {
       ["code"]=>
      string(3) "200"
      ["body"]=>
     object(stdClass)#8 (9) {
        ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "df98863d80aa0c89f5e359a4f3e10b5a"
    ["thumb_exists"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bytes"]=>
    int(0)
    ["path"]=>
    string(1) "/"
    ["is_dir"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["size"]=>
    string(7) "0 bytes"
    ["root"]=>
    string(10) "app_folder"
    ["contents"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (12) {
        ["revision"]=>
        int(1)
        ["rev"]=>
        string(9) "109a31b3c"
        ["thumb_exists"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["bytes"]=>
        int(45)
        ["modified"]=>
        string(31) "Tue, 21 Aug 2012 12:26:04 +0000"
        ["client_mtime"]=>
        string(31) "Tue, 21 Aug 2012 12:26:04 +0000"
        ["path"]=>
        string(20) "/api_upload_test.txt"
        ["is_dir"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["icon"]=>
        string(15) "page_white_text"
        ["root"]=>
        string(7) "dropbox"
        ["mime_type"]=>
        string(10) "text/plain"
        ["size"]=>
        string(8) "45 bytes"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (10) {
        ["revision"]=>
        int(3)
        ["rev"]=>
        string(9) "309a31b3c"
        ["thumb_exists"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["bytes"]=>
        int(0)
        ["modified"]=>
        string(31) "Tue, 21 Aug 2012 14:09:26 +0000"
        ["path"]=>
        string(14) "/dsdsdsdsdsdsd"
        ["is_dir"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["icon"]=>
        string(6) "folder"
        ["root"]=>
        string(7) "dropbox"
        ["size"]=>
        string(7) "0 bytes"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#11 (10) {
        ["revision"]=>
        int(4)
        ["rev"]=>
        string(9) "409a31b3c"
        ["thumb_exists"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["bytes"]=>
        int(0)
        ["modified"]=>
        string(31) "Tue, 21 Aug 2012 15:29:22 +0000"
        ["path"]=>
        string(14) "/ghhhhhhhhhhhh"
        ["is_dir"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["icon"]=>
        string(6) "folder"
        ["root"]=>
        string(7) "dropbox"
        ["size"]=>
        string(7) "0 bytes"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way of getting the url. The full path is not given in the array from dropbox. You have to specify media in the request, and the full path is given, which expires every 4 hours.

ie

```
$media = $dropbox->media($path);
```